# Rails Unpermitted parameter using nested forms and paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, nested-forms, parameters

Im creating a website where a User can post an ad of a Property , which can have many Photos .

I have been on this problem for 2 days now , none of the answers I've found have worked for this problem.

Heres the main program from where the issue is I believe .
I have tested many different versions from this code and none have been successful .

The params hash  in the console returns correct values , its just the manipulation of it causes the problems .

> {"utf8"=>"✓", 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"3OWguFpgwOYaLmQ4szRmPK/i13kLRr4XT1hcU6YEVlgml1iK1OzAg5c9UyETK1MiqdpoHYLcDGgx4aGd/FaZJg==",
>
> "property"=>{  "title"=>"asda",  "price"=>"3",  "numberOfBeds"=>"4", 
>   "toilets"=>"34",  "description"=>"salads", 
>   "photo"=>{"property_pic"=>#,
>   @original_filename="ASC_0321.jpg",  @content_type="image/jpeg", 
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"property[photo][property_pic]\";
>   filename=\"ASC_0321.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}, 
>   "commit"=>"Create Ad"}

*property.rb*

```
    class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :photos  , dependent: :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos , reject_if: lambda  {|t| t['photo'].nil? 
}
    end
```

*properties_controller.rb*

```
  def new
    @property = Property.new
    @photo  = @property.photos.new
  end

  def create

     @property  = current_user.properties.new(params[:property])

     @property.photos.new(params[[:photo][:property_pic]])
    if @property.save
      redirect_to property_path @property
    else
      render :edit
    end

  end

 def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:title,:price,:numberOfBeds,:toilets,:description , photo:[:property_pic])
  end
```

*properties/new.html.erb*

```
<div class="wrapper_skinny">

  <%= form_for @property do |p| %>

      <%= p.label :title %>
      <%= p.text_field :title %> <br><br>

      <%= p.label :price %>
      <%= p.number_field :price %> <br><br>

      <%= p.label :numberOfBeds %>
      <%= p.number_field :numberOfBeds %> <br><br>

      <%= p.label :toilets %>
      <%= p.number_field :toilets %> <br><br>

      <%= p.label :description %>
      <%= p.text_area :description %> <br><br>

      <%= p.fields_for :photo  do |builder|  %>
          <%= builder.label :property_pic %>
          <%= builder.file_field :property_pic %>
      <% end %> <br><br>


      <%= p.submit "Create Ad" , class:"button button-chosen"%>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried renaming the `photo:` in your `property_params` method to `photos_attributes:`? That could be the cause of some issues.

Comment: hi @Zoran , thanks for the comment , I still get unpermitted parameter photo , although with the adjustment i just made , the program doesn't crash when i submit my form .

Comment: Also, there should be `<%= p.fields_for :photos %>`. Association name needs to match. You will probably notice that all your fields for photos are gone after that change, this is correct and it means it works. Just add `@property.photos.build` in your controller and all should work.

Comment: where should _@property.photos.build_  be added ? will i add this line instead of this  >> `@property.photos.new(params[[:photo][:property_pic]])`

@BroiSatse

Comment: When you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you do not `build` it yourself. You just pass it in with a hash called `others_attributes`.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @stringRay2014 - You actually have it in the code already, so just ignore this step. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to `Muhamad`'s answer, here's what I'd do (several changes):

```
#app/models/property.rb
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :photos
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, reject_if: :all_blank #-> seems like you're doing this incorrectly
end

#app/controllers/properties_controller.rb
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @property = current_user.properties.new
      @property.photos.build
   end

   def create
      @property = current_user.properties.new property_params
      @property.save
   end

   private

   def property_params
       params.require(:property).permit(:title,:price,:number_of_beds,:toilets,:description , photos_attributes: [:property_pic])
   end
end
```

This should resolve your issue (your params show you're passing the nested form attributes through, although you'll need to ensure you use the [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) helper:

```
#app/views/properties/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @property do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo| %>
       <%= photo.file_field :property_pic %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

## Notes

**snake_case**

Always, always, **always** call `files` and `attributes` by their [`snake_case`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) name. Call classes by their [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) name, everything else by snake case.

-

**HTML**

Your HTML can also be improved big time:

```
#app/views/properties/new.html.erb
 <%= form_for @property do |p| %>

      <% options = [[:title, "text"], [:price, "number"], [:number_of_beds, "number"], [:toilets, "number"], [:description, "area"]] %>
 
      <% options.each do |type,input| %>
         <% input = "text_area" if input == "area" %>
         <%= p.label type %>
         <%= p.send(input, type)
      <% end %>

      <%= p.fields_for :photo  do |builder|  %>
          <%= builder.label :property_pic %>
          <%= builder.file_field :property_pic %>
      <% end %>

      <%= p.submit "Create Ad" , class:"button button-chosen"%>
  <% end %>
```

Also, **don't use HTML for styling** - only use CSS.

People use `<p>` and `<br>` to create spaces in their application, when `margin-top`/`margin-bottom` is the correct way to do it in the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried it a couples days ago in rails 4.

You have to change your `new` method into this to add `property_id` in photo object.

```
def new
  @property = Property.new
  @property.photos.new
end
```

Then, in your `create` method. I thought, you do not need to manual you photo and render to `new` method.

```
def create
  @property  = current_user.properties.new(property_params)
  if @property.save
    redirect_to property_path @property
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Next, you have to edit your `field_for` form into

```
<%= p.fields_for :photos  do |builder|  %>
  <%= builder.label :property_pic %>
  <%= builder.file_field :property_pic %>
<% end %>
```

Finally, change your strong parameters into

```
def property_params
  params.require(:property).permit(:title,:price,:numberOfBeds,:toilets,:description, photos_attributes: [:id, :property_pic])
end
```

I hope it can help you. This is how to make [rails 4 nested form](http://www.amooma.de/screencasts/2015-01-22-nested_forms-rails-4.2/)